# java - reading xml file from jar

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

I am trying to read the an xml configuration from a jar file deployed to dm-server

here is the code

```
Reader fileReader = null;
try {
 fileReader = new FileReader("test.xml");
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
 fnfex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioex) {
 ioex.printStackTrace();
}
```

i was able to read it if i just write a junit test w/o the jar and w/o the dm-server.

the test is packed into the jar and is at the root of the jar file.

please help!!!!

thanks,
A

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to a read file from jar in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-to-a-read-file-from-jar-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the Class's `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` methods to read files from within the jar.

This can be done like this:

```
Reader fileReader = null;

InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.xml");
if (null != is) {
    fileReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
}
```

Note that `getResourceAsStream` returns null if it can't find the file.

Edit:
Corrected test.xml to /test.xml

Also note that the `Class<T>` version of [`getResourceAsStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) defers to the `ClassLoader`'s [`getResourceAsStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) or [`getSystemResourceAsStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) as appropriate.

Comment: getResourceAsStream returns null, i have the xml in the root of the jar, is this the correct way of calling it?

InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.xml");

Comment: @Shah:  My mistake, it appears you do need a `/` before `test.xml`.  I'll fix it in a moment.

Comment: I tried this and it still returns null for me. I place my file in the resources folder.

Answer (score 4):

[ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) will allow you to read resources from within a .jar file. If your file is at the root of the .jar file then:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/test.xml");
```

will give you an InputStream from that file.