# Java InputStream fails to read file from within JAR

Tags: java, jar, inputstream

I am trying to read a file from my executable .jar file but it keeps getting null values.

I have this code:

```
public DanceEventTicketScanner(String txtfile){
    sv = new ScannerView(this);
    findcode = false;
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/copy.csv");
    if (is == null) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Resource not located.");
}
```

In the JAR file i have (as normal) a folder containing all my .class files and in the same directory a folder named resources which holds the copy.csv file.

This code however does not recognize the file.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-can-i-read-file-from-jar-in-java

Comment: In the same directory as what? /resources would need to be in the root of the JAR file for your code to work.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the first slash:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/copy.csv");
```

Answer (score 2):

getClass().getResourceAsStream(..) will use a path relative to the class (so inc. package dirs). getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(..) will use an absolute path. So change your code and get the class loader and it will work.

Comment: so if i use the second one you said, would i still be just giving "/resources/copy.csv" as the parameter?

Comment: This answer is not correct. See the Javadoc. If an absolute path is specified it will use it.