# Java Eclipse(RFT) : Cannot read ressource in jar

Tags: java, jar, resources

My project was executing fine until I try to create a jar with it...
From this class /TS_Generic_Engine/auto_engine_class/Resources.java
I am parsing this xml file: /TS_Generic_Engine/resources/values/strings.xml

```
String stringFilename = "resources/values" + langId + "/strings.xml"; 
InputStream fXmlFileStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("../" + stringFilename);

    if ( fXmlFileStream == null ) {
        if (language == RESOURCE_LANGUAGE.LANG_DEFAULT) {
            System.out.println("WARNING: No default strings resource found. Expected: " + stringFilename);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Works fine, but when I export my project in a jar I get 'Exported with compile warnings' for most of my java files..

When I try to run this jar, there is this output:

```
WARNING: No default strings resource found. Expected: resources/values/strings.xml
WARNING: Resources have not been initialized.
WARNING: Resources have not been initialized.
WARNING: Resources have not been initialized.
Exception occurred during playback of script [UserControlScript] [CRFCN0019E: RationalTestScriptException on line 56 of script UserControlScript - java.lang.NullPointerException: null.].
```

If I unzip my jar, locations of files are MyJar.zip/resources/values/string.xml and  MyJar.zip/auto_engine_class/Resources.java.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Zubzub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720436/zubzub) worked for me

[Java InputStream fails to read file from within JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231441/java-inputstream-fails-to-read-file-from-within-jar)