# Java Class Read a Yaml Inside Jar

Tags: java, jar, yaml

I am trying to read a file inside my jar from another class inside the jar.  However I am continually getting the same error:  Caught: class java.io.FileNotFoundException while attempting to read metrics: metrics.yml

At first I had my code do something like this, assuming it was from the path of the class:

```
String yamlPath = ".." + File.separator + ".." + File.separator + ".." + File.separator + ".." + File.separator + "myYaml.yml";

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(yamlPath));
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(isr);
yamlObj = (HashMap) javaYAML.load(input);
```

I also did this assuming it might take the path from the base of the jar:

```
String yamlPath = "myYaml.yml";

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(yamlPath));
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(isr);
yamlObj = (HashMap) javaYAML.load(input);
```

I then noticed this thread [How to read a file from jar in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-to-a-read-file-from-jar-in-java) and found out that I needed a "/" before my path.  I tried both methods above using the slash as well.

```
String yamlPath = File.seperator + ".." + File.separator + ".." + File.separator + ".." + File.separator + ".." + File.separator + "myYaml.yml";

OR

String yamlPath = File.seperator + "myYaml.yml";
```

I am completely lost on what to do about this error now.  Is there something I am not getting about the jar structure?  Why can my file not be found.  Thanks in advance for any help / information.

Sorry, I forgot to mention where it is in the JAR:
The class is in the following path:  com/a/b/c/myclass.class
The yaml is in the following path:  myYaml.yml

Comment: It is no longer a file in Jar, where is it located exactly in jar ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi Sorry about that.  The question is now updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File inside Jar is no longer a File, Change inputStream creation with this

```
InputStream in = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myYaml.yml");
```

Assuming your `.yml` file is at root of jar

Comment: Thank you much.  This does work.  For some reason I didn't notice it in the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file");
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow for me, i have to add '/' in front of the file name.

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = Xx.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.yml");
```

**From java doc:**

Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:

If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
modified_package_name/name
Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

And after i checked more detailed information, my solution is same as

```
InputStream in = Xx.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.yml");
```