# How to load a File within a Jar that is not relative to the Class its loaded from

Tags: java, file, jar, loading

I am trying to load a file that is within a jar file. I try to get the file to load in a BufferedReader. For example:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
```

where fileName is my string from the root of the Jar file: something like this "resources/text.txt"

I am having a hard time finding out how to make this happen. Obviously FileReader will not work since it reads from the file system.

Anyone that can help me out?

Comment: Unless there are classes loaded from this jar file the only way I can see is to treat it like an archive. There's an answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-to-a-read-file-from-jar-in-java#answer-13030711 on how to do it.

Comment: Is the jar in question in your classpath? Or is it just some file out in the filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the classloader to get the [resource as a stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/text.txt"), "utf-8");
```

Note that you need to specific the correct character encoding for the content.

Comment: *Jar that is not relative to the Class its loaded from* -OP

Comment: Perhaps a clarification is needed. I read that to indicate that the file is not in the same jar as the class being read from, not that the resource is not on the classpath.

Comment: Sry it's getting late for me here and I am a bit tired. My English suffers from this. The file is indeed IN the Jar file but not relative to the class (which is in a packet somewhere deeper in the jar file).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access a file within the same jar as your running program you should use

```
final InputStream inputStream = ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

Comment: Tried this method it did not work for me tho :( raised an NullPointerException. Thanks for your effort tho.

Comment: This may be because you aren't using the "utf-8" parameter that Brett Okken suggests

Comment: Calling getResourceAsStream on the Class will only look for resources relative to the package of the Class used.