# Libgdx cant load font from jar file

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx

I am trying to initiate a BitmapFont, when I run my project it works but when I jarsplice the project and then run it I get this.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeExcepti
on: Error reading file: assets\texture\font.fnt (Absolute)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:144)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.<init>(Bitmap
Font.java:835)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:106)
        at catt.main.Game.create(Game.java:105)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplic
ation.java:136)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplicati
on.java:114)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets\texture\font.fnt (The system ca
nnot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:140)
        ... 5 more
```

This is how I load the font.

```
fontTexture = new Texture("assets/texture/font.tga");
buttonFont = new BitmapFont(new FileHandle("assets/texture/font.fnt"), new TextureRegion(fontTexture), true);
titleFont = new BitmapFont(new FileHandle("assets/texture/font.fnt"), new TextureRegion(fontTexture), true);
```

They're all all the fields are public static.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3369794/4125191) - by default files come from the filesystem, not from the jar.

Answer (score 1):

LibGDX [has already a function to get Filehandle directly from JAR](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Files.html#internal-java.lang.String-). I load fonts like this:

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("texture/font.fnt"));
```

You should also make sure you have correctly linked assets folder.