# Including pictures and sound files in a runnable jar file from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have many sound and picture files I am using in a pokemon game I'm writing with Eclipse. Everything runs perfectly in Eclipse, but when I export it as a runnable jar, I get an error that the media is unavailable when I try running it.

This is the code I'm using for playing an mp3 file:

```
    File file = new File("src/pokemon/mp3s/opening.mp3");
    final String mediaLocation = file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();
    Media media = new Media(mediaLocation);
    mp = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

After exporting as a runnable jar, I execute it with java -jar Pokemon2.jar and get this error message:

Exception in thread "Main" MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\src\pokemon\mp3s\opening.mp3 
The system cannot find the path specified

How do I make my runnable jar be able to locate these additional resources?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to a read file from jar in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-to-a-read-file-from-jar-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployed jar file doesn't contains source files or src folder.
It is your IDE which make source files compiled and put them at other place, (e.g. in netbeans inside build\classes). And when you deploy your project it is your mp3 file will be present inside that jar file, not in `src` folder.

You should try another approach.
suppose your file is present in **src/pokemon/mp3s/opening.mp3**
and a class is present in **src/pokemon/Referer.java**

Now you can access your `mp3` file by taking `Referer` class as reference :

```
URL fileUrl = Referer.class.getResource("mp3s/opening.mp3");
```

Answer (score 1):

Files in a jar are not accessible as regular files. Instead you have to access them with `getResource`, which works when they are in the jar and out.

```
getClass().getResource("/pokemon/mp3s/opening.mp3");
```

Comment: Mind explaining why your answer is the solution?