# How to read image as FileInputStream from source folder?

Tags: java, image, file, netbeans

I have been trying to upload `image` to database. So I made a `browse` button to go through directories and get the image.  Suppose if no image is selected, a `default image` will be uploaded to the database. The image is stored in a folder named `'resources'` under source folder.In the image, helper is the folder containting .java files and below is the `resources` folder[image: helper directory contains .java files and below is the resource folder in this image] I am uploading the image as `FileInputStream` and the code is

```
File pic=new File(imgloc);
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(pic);
```

If the image is not selected to upload a default image my code is

```
File pic=new File(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/profile1.png").getFile());
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(pic);
```

And my query to database is

```
    ps.setBinaryStream(1,fis ,(int) pic.length()); //While substituing for '?' in query
```

After build to jar it produce `FileNotFoundException` when trying to add default image. May be the question is asked several times I didn't find solution in that.  I want read the image as file..Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cant read the source folder from runtime - the resource should be on you classpath

Comment: I have created a `resources` folder under source folder packages

Comment: and I said *you cant read the source folder from runtime*

Comment: But i can able to see the `resources` folder when i opened the jar file with `winrar`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think We can read file at runtime from source folder.

Comment: Are they in below directory containing your class files?  see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608824/2310289

Comment: @afzalex Sure if you fully path it.  The OP us using getResource.  As per javadocs, *This method locates the resource through the system class loader (see getSystemClassLoader()).*  If you can provide some code showing otherwise please do so.

Comment: I have tried `ClassLoader` too.. That too didnt make favour. and @ScaryWombat It is saved as a directory below class files

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have described the path fully `/resources/profile1.png' . I thing thats enough path.  If anything missed please tell what to add in my code

Comment: show the folders and files in your jar (just relevant ones)

Comment: @ScaryWombat None answers worked from the question u marked as duplicate

Comment: @previn see my answer

Comment: @previn Have a look at my answer

Comment: @afzalex A very nice answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to help illustrate I create a project with a source directory

```
src
```

below source I had a package `starthere` with a class `Main`

I create another source directory `xxx` and put in a file `a.txt`

I also created under `xxx` a directory called `text` and put in a file named `b.txt`

Also I created under `src` a directory called `other` and put in a file called `c.txt`

My code is

```
    URL url = Main.class.getResource("/a.txt");
    System.out.println(url);
    URL url2 = Main.class.getResource("/text/b.txt");
    System.out.println(url2);
    URL url3 = Main.class.getResource("/other/c.txt");
    System.out.println(url3);
```

and my output is

> D:\temp>java -cp ab.jar starthere.Main
>
> jar:file:/D:/temp/ab.jar!/a.txt
>
> jar:file:/D:/temp/ab.jar!/text/b.txt
>
> jar:file:/D:/temp/ab.jar!/other/c.txt

**edit**

As you are not wanting to use a File, but simply the InputStream, you can use

```
InputStream fis = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/a.txt");
```

and then set using `ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis);`

Comment: Yes bro, I tried this thing. After this code i used `File pic=new File(url.to URI);` because i need to load it to database Worked in code bro But not in jar. It showed exception `illegal argument exception: URI is not hierarchical`.

Comment: I am not following you.  The error is a completely different error.  Also this code `File pic=new File(url.to URI);` does not make sense at all

Comment: Bro sorry for mistakes made by me, But my question itself is i want to get image as `file` Then only i can add it to database

Comment: As per my code, are you getting an URL?  This is the first step

Comment: yeah bro. I got `url`. Then kindly say what shld i do

Comment: Working in code bro. But in jar `file:\C:\Users\Previn\Documents\NetBeansProjects\helper\dist\helper.jar!\resources\profile1.png
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\Previn\Documents\NetBeansProjects\helper\dist\helper.jar!\resources\profile1.png (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`.  This exception arises.

Comment: Well as you don't really want the file, your just want the inputstream, use `getResourceAsStream` instead and then use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream(int,%20java.io.InputStream)

Answer (score 0):

Consider following package structure

```
/
/testing_package
/testing_package/Main.java
/testing_package/Image.png
```

Now Here is a program to get Image.png and put it in database

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        System.out.println(Main.class.getResource("image.jpg"));
        //PreparedStatement as ps
        ps.setBinaryStream(1, Main.class.getResourceAsStream("image.jpg")));
    }
}
```

**Thing to keep in mind**
When using `getResource(...)` or `getResourceAsStream(...)` use relative location to the class instance whose function you are invoking.

[Have a look at this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27348157/3626698)