# Accessing resource from a jar shared library

Tags: java, jar, resources

From test.java, how can I access for reading the Contact.xml file located in the contacts.jar library ?

The bellow code returns null.

```
package views;

import fr.hznteam.contacts.Contact;
import fr.hznteam.errors.ResourceException;

import java.io.InputStream;


    public class Test {

        private static final String TAG = "Test ";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ResourceException {

            InputStream is = Contact.class.getResourceAsStream("/fr/hznteam/contacts/sql/Contact.xml");
            System.out.println(TAG + "resource from jar " + is);

        }
```

The package structure :

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-to-a-read-file-from-jar-in-java

Comment: I made a mistake building my testing environment. Actually as mentioned in your link that works fine !

Answer (score 0):

this works (see above comment). Inside an object instance use

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/absolute/class_path/to/resource.file"))
```