# ClassLoader shows wrong path on Linux

Tags: java, linux, filenotfoundexception

I am using classLoader to load xml files located under `/src/XMLS` :

```
String m_path = "XMLS/file.xml"

ClassLoader cl = getClass.getClassLoader();
file f1 = new file(cl.getResource(m_path).getFile));
```

Running on windows it works fine but after export to jar and running it on Linux I get `FileNotFoundException` `- /XMLS/file.xml`.
I had tried this [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-to-read-a-file-from-jar-in-java) and I dont think that the problem is in the read from the `.jar` file. any other ideas for what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running it the same way both on Win and Linux? Or are you only running the exported JAR on Linux, and using some other way on Win? Is your classpath set properly when executing the JAR on Linux?

Comment: File names in linux are case sensitive, while on windows they are not - could it be that the cases don't match?

Comment: 1 -running  it the same way on both machines. 2 - I belive it is.

Comment: What is the Java commandline you are using to execute on Linux?

Comment: @JoseMartinez sh scipt_name.sh

Comment: @Dezza - I dont think so, I am reading the file from the jar(at least I hope so).

Comment: `sh scipt_name.sh` is *not* a Java command line. We need to know the actual command used to run the JAR, even if it's in some shell script.

Comment: The command inside the sh file - 'java -jar jar_name.jar'

Comment: So your main class is in the manifest file of the JAR?

Comment: yes, why does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work for a resource inside a jar file, which is not a file on the filesystem. Instead, you need to use `getResourceAsStream()`, which returns an `InputStream` to use directly:

```
InputStream in = someClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/XMLS/file.xml");
```