# Springboot running on Docker unable to read files from resources

Tags: docker, spring-boot, java-8, apache-poi

I have a springboot project with default structure. I have an excel file under resources/data. My program need to load excel file and dump data into different tables from each sheet.

When I run from Eclipse, program loads excel file correctly and everything looks good. However, when I deploy the same App on Docker, it fails to read the File from resources.

Have anyone encountered this issues? How have you solved it?

Comment: When we run an application from a Jar then, the way we read file needs to be changed. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-to-read-a-file-from-jar-in-java

Answer (score 6):

First of all try to check whether the Docker is a reason, or  there is an issue with java code. Spring boot creates an artifact that can be run with just `java -jar <your-spring-boot-artifact.jar>`

If this doesn't run even without docker, then you should change the way you access Excel files from spring boot application (your java code): 
if the file is in resources folder, it should be packaged into the spring boot artifact.

In this case, you have to use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` to access the file, and not rely on `java.io.File` API, because File API doesn't allow working with files inside a Jar, its not a regular filesystem.

Comment: Thank you, getResourceAsStream() worked as opposed to getFile, cheers