# How to get a file read in CMD written in foreign language(Korean)?

Tags: java, cmd

I'm fairly new to java. I'm making a text-based game right now.
I have a few conversations in Korean saved in text files. and I'm loading it in a method with BufferReader with a following code:

```
Path read = Paths.get("conversation.txt");       
try {
        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(read, Charset.forName("euc-kr"));

        String lineS = reader.readLine();

        while (lineS != null) {

                System.out.println(lineS);

            }
            lineS = reader.readLine();
            sc.nextLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot find the file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This doesn't have any problem if I run it in Eclipse. But if I run it in CMD, it makes error.[image]

I almost finished making this game, and I'm going to send it to my friends. But it is making errors here. How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: is this the code you have in Main.intro1() method (based on your stack trace)?

Comment: So `conversation.txt` is inside `jar` file when run from command line? Then it makes sense your file cannot be found. Also this has nothing to do with encoding of file

Comment: Piro, what does it mean when you said conversation.txt is inside jar file? what is jar file? conversation.txt file is in the regular java folder with bin folder and src folder

Comment: So how are you running your program? Jar file is like zip file with java classes, see [jar tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jar/info). I expected you created jar file (There is export option in eclipse for that) to distribute your game.

Comment: Okay. So I just created Jar file. and it works. but it still doesn't read the file written in Korean inside... it shows an error

Comment: at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file from jar in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-to-read-a-file-from-jar-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

check the file path and also check the permission of file folder and file.

Answer (score -1):

Try to print the absolute path the programme point to. And make a zip file include this programme and the text file to avoid the NoSuchFileException. Or make a jar file including the text file with eclipse. 
How about export jar file like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3ISJ.png)?

Comment: I literally have no idea what you mean....:// if you could give me an example with visual, that would be a lot easier to understand..