# my program can read txt file whilerunning on intellij but when i create jar file it can't read

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

```
reader = new Scanner(Paths.get(userDirectory + "/src/file.txt"));
```

my txt file is on src and program runs normally in IDE but jar file can't read my txt file
how can i solve this problem.

Comment: You can read the file by providing the full/absolute path in the code like `/your/dir/src/file.txt` or use the classloader to get the file path like: `String filePath = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile()` and then use the derived filePath

Comment: Please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-to-read-a-file-from-jar-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get same problem, but I don't know What are you using for "userDirectory".

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String userDirectory = "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Personal/testjarcreate";
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(Paths.get(userDirectory + "/src/file.txt"));
    System.out.println(reader.next());
}
```

}
The content are "test,test" in file.txt's.
When it build with this main, I get "test,test" result on terminal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).